# Is SAP free crystal report developer version for Microsoft visual studio 2012/2013 is only for students or developers

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

Is SAP free crystal report developer version for Microsoft visual studio 2012/2013 is only for students or developers for practice or We can use it for commercially for clients .I did not see any commercial version in SAP site.Is there any free version available  for commercially reports in Microsoft visual studio 2012/2013 in SAP site.I want to use it for my client and I am looking free version.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing - not programming

Answer (score 0):

It can be use freely for commercial applications but not with ASP.Net. You are limited to WinForms application.

Have a look at http://scn.sap.com/thread/1602315

Comment: can you share the link.where i can purchase the license for microsoft visual studio 2012/2013

Comment: I checked the link but there does not mention we can use it for asp.net ?

Comment: This editor is very different.I think this is desktop editor

Comment: The version that you have downloaded for free is the light version. The version you need to use is the full version. I encourage you to contact SAP directly as no body other than them is able to provide you the exact answer to that question.

Comment: light version we can use free for any commercial reports.

Comment: even web? you have a link for that because in older versions a key was required!

Comment: as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288410(v=vs.71).aspx 

"Providing the license key is a mandatory step whenever you deploy a Crystal Reports for Visual Studio .NET application. "

Comment: Yes web I want to deploy on web.